# Issues showing validation errors with in Blazor PWA VS-2019 solution

Tags: visual-studio, validation, blazor, progressive-web-apps, data-annotations

Our VS-2019 solution is for a PWA template configured for **.Net CORE-5**.

I am having difficulty coding for CRUD validation in the PWA application code.

The VS-2019 solution contains three projects.
The **DB-model** class code AND the custom **ValidationAttribute** code are in the **SHARED project**.
The **DB-API** interfaces and code are defined in the **SERVER project** (using "repositories" for each model-class).
The **UI "CRUD" HTML** and `@code` are in the **CLIENT project**.

We use DataAnnotation and custom ValidationAttribute(s) for each of the CRUD fields in the model-classes and fields as appropriate.

We have a requirement that when ADDing or EDITing a "Customer" record, the "CustomerName" must be unique from all other "customers".
We have a custom ValidationAttribute that gets called during validation that should appear in the UI when the "CustomerName" is not unique.
The algorithm to test for other duplicate "customer-name" is rather simple, BUT it requires fetching the list of "customer-names" from all of the other "customers".

***So the problem is***, how do I fetch the list of "customer-names" from the **SERVER** code when calling from the **SHARED** code to determine whether the "customer-name" is unique or not?  The following INJECT code (defined in SERVER project) always returns NULL for the "CustomerService" variable in the SHARED code -- **thus preventing the ability to get data from the database**.

`[Inject] public ICustomerService CustomerService { get; set; }`

We have the following PROJECT DEPENDENCIES in the VS-solution:

- CLIENT depends on *SHARED*.
- SERVER depends on *SHARED and CLIENT*.
- SHARED has NO dependencies -- *BECAUSE* -- VS complains of circular dependencies.

I am at a loss as to "what to do next".

*Additional consideration*...in the CLIENT/UI **OnSubmit** event , I have successfully tested for unique using the DB function **BUT BUT BUT** ... I don't know how to make the ErrorMessage appear in the validation-summary.  Any thoughts?

Your questions, comments and solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

`[Inject] public ICustomerService CustomerService { get; set; }`

Is Blazor syntax, it won't work on the Server. It is called property injection and only works in Components (.razor or .razor.cs files).

Use constructor-injection and make sure the service is registered in the Server Startup class.

> how do I fetch the list of "customer-names" from the SERVER code when calling from the SHARED code

You can't. The dependencies you list are correct, the Shared project does not have access to the Server.
Unique validation  has to be done on the Server.

---

Update:

you don't have to "get the list" to verify uniqueness. The basis would be calling a method like `Task<bool> AnyAsync(...)` on your Repository or datalayer.

When you want this validation on the Client you will have to make an API endpoint for it.

The Validation attributes can stay in the Shared project, but afaik [Unique] will only take effect when you generate the Database schema.

Constructor injection (Server or Client) looks like

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    public DataAccess(HttpClient http)
    {
        _http = http;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Henk...  You helped me very much.  So now I am really stuck.  Can I ask "how" am I to code for this server-validation using Blazor?  Do I remove the custom ValidationAttribute from the model-field?  What code should I have available in the component's code to allow server-validation to occur at the server?  Hope you can help me with (a) links to solution(s) or (b) some code-snippets with "locations" of the code (HTML/@code{}/SHARED/SERVER/STARTUP.cs...other).  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Henk...Can you please explain your comment: "Use constructor-injection...".  I know little about the Startup.cs and service-registration. Thanks. John